# Why is Vagrant making up an incorrect subnet when it's just supposed to port-forward?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Host is Windows 8.1; provider is VirtualBox 4.3.4; Vagrant version is 1.3.5.

Host has just a single NIC, wired, with IP 192.168.1.100.

Vagrantfiles reads:

```
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "init.pp"
    puppet.options="--verbose --debug"
```

However, following `vagrant up`, the VM gets a completely **wrong** IP address. `ifconfig` for the guest reads:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64:~$ ifconfig                   
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:1a:b6:5e         
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.25
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe1a:b65e/64 Scope:Link    
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1    
          RX packets:356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:239 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                          
          RX bytes:38937 (38.9 KB)  TX bytes:33157 (33.1 KB)
```

Why is Vagrant totally ignoring the port forwarding setting on the vagrantfile? IP address should be `192.168.1.x`and instead I get this random `10.0.2.15`. Any ideas?

**Edit:** Host can't even ping `10.0.2.15`. No response, even when the VM is up. Something is very broken.

**Edit 2:** Now I'm getting `/sbin/ip addr flush dev eth1 2> /dev/null` on 2 different systems. Argh.

Comment: did you review the interface eth1??

Comment: What do you mean by review?

Comment: when i execute ifconfig i see two interface : eth0 and eth1. the last one take the ip address from my Vagrantfile configuration

Comment: I'm sorry ezuk, but I meant revise... Sorry again for my poor english

Comment: I think this has to do with the way the machine was packaged. https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2811

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ssh into the machine

Delete the file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

Exit the machine

Do a "vagrant reload"

I think that does the trick =]

Answer (score 1):

port-forwarding means that packets received on mentioned port will be forwarded to the guest. in your example localhost:8080 should redirected to the vm's service listening on vm's 80 port.

Regarding "random" 10.0.2.15, usually this IP assigned to the guest if VM configured with NAT attachment, this mean that guest absolutely invisible from outside (except port-forward, but this access possible only via host). And of course you can't ping guest from the host only in opposite direction (from guest to host).

Comment: So how do you make it visible?